# Realm error given when saving

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a database that is populated like so:

```
for defJson in listofDefinitions {
    let newItemOfStock = Item()
    print(defJson)
    try! realm.write {
        newItemOfStock.AverageCost = defJson["AverageCost"] as! Int
        newItemOfStock.Barcode = defJson["Barcode"] as! String
        newItemOfStock.Description = defJson["Description"] as! String
        newItemOfStock.InternalUnique = defJson["InternalUnique"] as! Int
        newItemOfStock.LastCost = defJson["LastCost"] as! Int
        newItemOfStock.LimitToMainRegionUnique = defJson["LimitToMainRegionUnique"] as! Int
        newItemOfStock.Notes = defJson["Notes"] as! String
        newItemOfStock.StockCategoryUnique = defJson["StockCategoryUnique"] as! Int
        newItemOfStock.StockCode = defJson["StockCode"] as! String
        newItemOfStock.StockGroupUnique = defJson["StockGroupUnique"] as! Int
        newItemOfStock.UnitDescriptor = defJson["UnitDescriptor"] as! String

        self.newList.listOfItems.append(newItemOfStock)
    }
}
```

But before I populated the data I want to deleted the old data that is still in the realm database and I call this func:

```
func cleanOldData() {
    let itemListToBeRemoved = realm.objects(ListOfDefinitions)
    let itemToBeRemoved = realm.objects(Item)
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(itemListToBeRemoved)
        realm.delete(itemToBeRemoved)
    }
}
```

But if I call this method more than once this error is thrown:

```
'RLMException', reason: 'Adding a deleted or invalidated object to a Realm is not permitted'
```

How do I stop this from happening and still have a clean database before it is populated

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to delete all the data from your Realm (and not just the data for specific types), you can try using the `deleteAll()` API:

```
try! realm.write {
  realm.deleteAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
                    self.newList.listOfItems.append(newItemOfStock)
```

I suspect that maybe you fetch the object newList from the database, then you delete all the objects and then you try to add the newItemOfStock object to a reference of an object you have deleted.